# Change the color of an element with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I wanna change a svg with the help of a dropdown menu with javascript.

My javascript works fine when I wanna change a paragraph element. Then it clears the old class and gives a new based on the text of dropdown option.

But when I use it to change a svg image it works for any times. It gives a new class to the svg element. But the wiping out of the old class does not work and then its broken.

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
var pElem = document.getElementById('p')

// When a new <option> is selected
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() { 
  
  //get value text
  var colorValue= document.getElementById('select').options[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex].text;
  
  pElem.className = '';
  
  // Add that class to the <p>
  pElem.classList.add(colorValue);
})
```

```css
.grün {color: green;}
.gelb {color: yellow;}
.blau {color: blue;}
.rot {color: red;}
.pink {color: pink;}

svg {width: 20%;
    height: 20%;}
```

```html
<p id="p">Element</p>
<select id="select">
  <option selected>grün</option>
  <option>gelb</option>
  <option>blau</option>
  <option>rot</option>
  <option>pink</option>
</select>
```

Here SVG changing code:

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
var pElem = document.getElementById('one')

// When a new <option> is selected
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() { 
  
  //get value text
  var colorValue= document.getElementById('select').options[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex].text;
  
  pElem.className = '';
  
  // Add that class to the <p>
  pElem.classList.add(colorValue);
})
```

```css
.weiss {fill: white;}
.grün {fill: green;}
.gelb {fill: yellow;}
.blau {fill: blue;}
.rot {fill: red;}
.pink {fill: pink;}
```

```html
<svg id="one" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>

<p id="p">Element</p>
<select id="select">
  <option selected>grün</option>
  <option>gelb</option>
  <option>blau</option>
  <option>rot</option>
  <option>pink</option>
</select>
```

Comment: change `pElem.className = ''` to `pElem.classList = ''`;

Comment: I would use values instead of text and for the green option I would use `value="grun"`

Comment: Thank you guy! That works! Can you tell me why className is working on a 'p'  element?

Comment: @enxaneta I would, too. But the customer want it the other way. ;-)

Comment: The `className` property on an HTML element is a different type of object to the `className` property on an SVG element.  The way you alter its value is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `pElem.className = ''` to `pElem.classList = ''`.

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
var pElem = document.getElementById('one')

// When a new <option> is selected
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() { 
  
  //get value text
  var colorValue= document.getElementById('select').options[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex].text;
  
  pElem.classList = '';
  
  // Add that class to the <p>
  pElem.classList.add(colorValue);
})
```

```css
.weiss {fill: white;}
.grün {fill: green;}
.gelb {fill: yellow;}
.blau {fill: blue;}
.rot {fill: red;}
.pink {fill: pink;}
```

```html
<svg id="one" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>

<p id="p">Element</p>
<select id="select">
  <option selected>grün</option>
  <option>gelb</option>
  <option>blau</option>
  <option>rot</option>
  <option>pink</option>
</select>
```

This should fix your problem.

Links: [className docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), [classList docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Related tags: [css](/questions/tagged/css), [html](/questions/tagged/html), [classname](/questions/tagged/classname)

Comment: All works fine, but with one problem. The js works just when the cache is clean.